# Как подключить библиотеку в форму с++?

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli, map, библиотеки

У меня возникла проблема конкретно с библиотекой map. Не могу понять куда и как ее подключить чтоб например в button1_Click можно было ее использовать.

Comment: Вы о контейнере `map` из стандартной библиотеки? Или это какая-то левая библиотека `map`? Просто говорить о "библиотеке `map`" для стандартного `map` — то де, что говорить о "библиотеке `int`", например...

Comment: @Harry для стандартной

Comment: Тогда, как я понимаю, надо просто добавить `#include <map>` в исходный текст...

Comment: @Harry ну вроде да, я написал функцию в консоли которая использовала библиотеку map и вставил ее в событие кнопки.